# IE and Edge css mask

Tags: css, svg

```css
.icon{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url("https://filebin.net/ohqbnjapd3pb1ph1/_______________-________.svg?t=oy0jd7bb");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  mask:url("https://filebin.net/ohqbnjapd3pb1ph1/_______________-________.svg?t=oy0jd7bb") no-repeat 100%;
}

.icon:hover{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<span class="icon icon-filter"></span>
```

Greetings, i'm trynig to color the svg using mask but it won't work on Edge and IE.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks

Comment: @Pete thanks for a reference, by the way is there any alternative options to handle it? I've got solid svg files with one color and i need to change svg color on hover.

Comment: If it wasn't a background image, you could just change the fill: https://css-tricks.com/the-many-ways-to-change-an-svg-fill-on-hover-and-when-to-use-them/ or use a font icon

Comment: @Pete is it possible to put a svg file like tag, kind of innerHtml and then use fill? P.S. i'm a newbie on that.

Comment: You should be able to include the svg code directly in the html or include it as an image tag - see the link in the above comment, it has codepen examples